# Python bdist_rpm Requires Python

Tags: python

I would like to create a python based RPM that would get installed on a minimal CENTOS install that doesn't have Python.  Is there a way, through the bdist_rpm command to include the version of Python I used to build the Python script included in the RPM? Below is what I want to achieve

1. install CENTOS minimal image
2. run shell script that installs Python RPM and executes the Python binary

The thing I can't figure out is how to include Python in the script so that it gets installed when the RPM is and thusly allows the user installing the ability to run the Python script.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in an environment where Python is available as an RPM, you can use `bdist_rpm --requires ...`, or save that option in a `setup.cfg` file:

```
[bdist_rpm]
requires = name_of_rpm
```